# Filtering rows in mysql with possibility for more values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, row

I'm new in PHP and MySQL and i have some problems. 
[image: For me it is easier to explain with a screenshot]

For example here i would want to show all people, who can work with Wordpress, Joomla AND Typo3... In this case it should show only Mrs Mustermann
I tried WHERE name='joomla' OR name='wordpress' OR name='typo3', but it shows the people, who can work with any of the three... Sorry for my bad english

---

**EDIT**

OP note: providing example data is *not* hard, doesn't flippin matter how "easy" posting an image is

```
 nachname    vorname  email                name        id
 ---------   -------  -------------------  ---------- --- 
 Mustermann  Mrs                           joomla     148 
 Mustermann  Mrs                           wordpress  148 
 Mustermann  Mrs                           typo3      148 
 Mustermann  Muster   mustermann@gmail.de  wordpress  158 
 Mustermann  Muster   mustermann@gmail.de  typo3      158
```

---

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM ( SELECT 'Mustermann' AS nachname,'Mrs' AS vorname,'' AS email,'joomla' AS NAME,'148' AS id
         UNION ALL SELECT 'Mustermann','Mrs','','wordpress','148'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'Mustermann','Mrs','','typo3','148'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'Mustermann','Muster','mustermann@gmail.de','wordpress','158'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'Mustermann','Muster','mustermann@gmail.de','typo3','158'
       ) t
```

Comment: posting example data from mysql as a screenshot image may be easier for you, but it is certainly *not* easier for anyone else. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question  And is much easier for the reader if you format the example SQL WHERE conditions as code

Comment: *For me it is easier to explain with a screenshot* We do not heal by photo. CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO is safe.

Comment: Sorry... `code`($query = "SELECT nachname, vorname, email, name, user.id FROM user LEFT JOIN userskill ON user.id = userskill.userid LEFT JOIN skill ON userskill.skillid=skill.id";)

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical solution uses `group by` to aggregate rows having the same `nachname`, and then to filter with a `having` clause:

```
select nachname
from mytable
where name in ('joomla', 'wordpress', 'typo3')
group by id, nachname
having count(distinct name) = 3
```

I assumed that `id` is a unique identifier for `nachname`, so I added it to the `group by` clause; feel free to remove it if that's not the case.

This query gives you the `nachname`s that have worked for all three values in the `in` list.

It is quite easy to adapt the query to handle more (or less) `name`s, by modifying the `in` list and the target count.

If there are no duplicate `(nachname, name)` duplicates in the table, you can use `count(*)` instead of `count(distinct ...)`, which will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use next query to solve you problem:

```
SELECT 
    nachname, vorname, email, 
    CONCAT(s1.name,' ', s2.name,' ', s3.name) as skills,
    user.id 
FROM user 
JOIN userskill ON user.id = userskill.userid 
-- each of joins filter by demand skillname
JOIN skill s1 ON userskill.skillid=s1.id and s1.name = 'Wordpress'
JOIN skill s2 ON userskill.skillid=s1.id and s2.name = 'Joomla'
JOIN skill s3 ON userskill.skillid=s1.id and s3.name = 'Typo3'
;
```